# What should I do if my bounty is about to expire?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have a [hundred point bounty](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86765/reimer-tiemann-like-reaction-of-catechol-with-diiodomethane) that is about to expire in one day.

I have received discussion in comments, but no one has yet posted a conclusive answer. No one has asked for more clarification in my question. I [read this page](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/getting-answer-after-bounty-fails), but it's been 10 days since I posted the question and apparently there isn't any fault in the question language.

I understand bounties are not guarantees for any answer. I am not also afraid that I lost my hundred points. I am just worried that the bounty will go in waste. I don't understand what I should do now.

Can someone please guide me on what I can do to attract attention in the final days of my bounty?

Thanks!

Comment: It might not be the best approach for your particular question, but we also have a [meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3698/canonical-qa-proposing-a-patronage-system) that tries to circumvent the strict time limit on bounties for questions that require a detailed answer that might be tough to produce within the time frame.

Comment: @Tyberius Thanks for linking it! It seems that that meta post is about creating long term bounties for FAQ like questions, while mine seems to be more like long term bounties for difficult questions. Although the circumvention of the bounty is still the same.

Comment: the post didn't pick up a lot of steam at the time, but I liked the idea of avoiding the bounty time limit so I have tried to promote the post as a general way to post long term bounties.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately there really isn't much that you can do. Sometimes a bounty simply goes to "waste". With your bounty you are basically paying (forward) an advertisement fee. Once the agreed upon advertising time is up (7 days), as somewhat of a bonus the reputation amount will go to the answer you choose. If there is none, it is lost.

The only thing you could do is to go to chat and remind the people who are there, that there is a bounty about to expire. Don't do that too often though, as the regular visitors will also get annoyed by advertising question.

It happened to me a couple of times, too. I know it is not a happy situation, but sometimes that's just the way it is. All you can do for now is hope someone will still answer. Good Luck!

I advice to make sure before assigning the bounty to the question that there aren't any problems with it. You can ask for advice in chat and find out how to make a question more interesting for a broader audience. However, in some cases, there simply isn't an easy answer, or the specialist who would know it is not around. The score is usually a good indicator if that question sparked interest.

Comment: I appreciate your long feedback! Thanks! I'll try check in "the periodic table".